# How to properly get/set env vars during the build via cloudbuild.yaml?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-container-registry

I'm using Google Cloud Container Builder to build my images. I connected it to my GitHub repository so it is triggered by push to specific branch.
I provide some env variables to my build step explicitly and using prepositions.

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
...
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build', '-t', 'eu.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/project-name:${SHORT_SHA}', '.']
  env:
    - 'TEST_ENV=test123'
    - 'TEST=${_TEST}'
...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN printenv

...
```

I can see my env variables in build details at Env. Vars section of this build step when build is triggered: `TEST_ENV=test123 TEST=test_prepositon`

But when `RUN printenv` is executed I see only `HOSTNAME, SHLVL, HOME, PATH, PWD` env vars.

Where is my mistake? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is passing your environment variables to the `docker` command but not to the docker build context.

When you set environment variables via `env`, these envvars are set in the running container. But when docker executes a `docker build` it does not by default pass the environment though to the build context.

To set environment variables such that they are accessible in the build context via a `RUN` directive, pass your `docker build` a `--build-arg`.

[Here is Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) on setting build-time variables.

Comment: Is this the only way to pass environment variables to the build context?

Comment: Yes, this is how Docker works. See also the Docker documentation on how to explicitly set envvars in your Dockerfile using the ENV directive.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full example of what you are looking for.

cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: [
      "build",
      "-t",
      "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$SHORT_SHA",
      ".",
      "--build-args", "SOME_ARG=${_VAR_NAME_FROM_GOOGLE_TRIGGERS}"
    ]
```

Dockerfile:

```sh
ARG SOME_ARG
ENV SOME_ENV_VAR_NAME=${SOME_ARG}
```

The variable `SOME_ENV_VAR_NAME` could be accessed right in the docker container

Also, I would like to add 2 great articles that explain docker arg and env:

- https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-pass-environment-variables/
- https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/

Comment: It looks like `--build-args` should be `--build-arg` (no 's')?